# How to do async validation with Hapi + Joi

Tags: validation, asynchronous, joi, hapi

How can i do async validation using Hapi + Joi custom extension?

Given a simple server route like this that leverages a custom Joi extension:

```
  {
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/user/{userId}',
    options: {
      validate: {
        params: j.object({
          userId: j.user().required(),  // Custom 'user' type
        }),
      },
    },
    handler: getUserHandler,
  },
```

...and extension definition:

```
const joiExtended = Joi.extend(
  {
    type: 'user',
    base: Joi.string(),
    validate: async (value, helpers) => {
      // return value based on async db query
    },
    ...
  },
)
```

...the problem I run into is the handler is called before the validation routine completes.  I need a way to tell Joi to `await` the validation result. Some things that seemed promising that didn't pan out:

1. use `base: Joi.any()` - and then use the `external` function to do validation.  I think this would work but I don't see how to implement it in the extension.  I tried using `overrides` and specifying `external` there but couldn't make it work.
2. use `validateAsync` - this seems like the most obvious option but again I don't see where to specify using this function vs. standard `validate`.  It is not an option on the route `validate.params` object